# R Merge 2 data.frames with similar variables

Tags: r

Is it possible to merge two data.frame without having exactly the same variables in the two df.

Example:

```
df1 <-  data.frame(C=c("1Q","4R"),B= c("A","plane"))
df <-  data.frame(A=c(1,2),B=c("A (Inc", "plane (Inc)"))

> df
#  A           B
#1 1      A (Inc
#2 2 plane (Inc)

> df1
#   C     B
#1 1Q     A
#2 4R plane
```

Is it possible to merge df1 and df? Here I don't want to pre-modify the data in the dfs for the match to occur. I'm would like the merge to discard the (Inc), while keeping it in the dfs. An obvious soluion in this dumb example would be `cbind()`, but it's really the merge that I'm looking for.

My merged data.frame would be:

```
df

#    C     B A           B
# 1 1Q     A 1      A (Inc
# 2 4R plane 2 plane (Inc)
```

Comment: 'append(df1,df)' Note that your second 'B' will become 'B.1'

Comment: Changing variable names isn't hard ( i.e. `names(df) <- names(df1)` ) and systematically ignoring variable names is a good way to intoduce a hard-to-find bug.

Comment: ... *"would like the merge to discard the (Inc), while keeping it in the dfs."* This does not make sense to me. Your suggested output neither discards it nor is there anything to suggest that you've done anything other than `cbind` them. Are you trying to pair the "A" in `df` with the "A*" in `df1`? Please provide a more informative example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed like this:

```
> merge(df1,transform(df, B = gsub("[[:space:]]*\\(Inc.*$","",df$B), B1=df$B))
      B  C A          B1
1     A 1Q 1      A (Inc
2 plane 4R 2 plane (Inc)
```